# Swift Xcode Button not showing next view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to code a button that simply switches to the next view. So I embedded the first ViewController into a navigation controller then I dragged in another view controller, created a new class name ViewController2 and associated that class with the second ViewController and came the second view controller a storyboard id:"view2". Then in the Button's function I added this code:

```
@IBAction func newGamePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as   
ViewController2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}
```

However when i click on the button, literally nothing happens!!! what am i doing wrong???

Comment: the button is connected to the IB action function newGamePressed I assume?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func newGamePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
let VC1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2")
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)
self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Just try with this code.